# Place a cursor to the end in all text boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**SOLUTION:**
As mm8 in the comments pointed, the solution is with ScrollToHorizontalOffset. I got it to work by modifying mm8's answer and here's the working code:

```
inputTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(inputTextBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(inputTextBox.Text.Length).Right);
```

It's a little lengthy, but it works perfectly!

I have a program with two text boxes:

```
<TextBox x:Name="InputTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,0"
      Text="{Binding FileToConvert, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  /> 

<TextBox x:Name="OutputTextBlock" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,0"
      Text="{Binding OutputFilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When one of the text boxes gets updated, the second one is updated as well with stuff, but both of the text boxes should scroll to the end of the text inserted. This is because sometimes those input/output directories can be very long.

I already tried to get those two textboxes, and edit their properties in the code behind like this:

```
...
var inputTextBox = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) grid.GetElementByName("InputTextBlock");          
var outputTextBox = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) grid.GetElementByName("OutputTextBlock");

inputTextBox.Focus();
inputTextBox.Select(inputTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
inputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();

outputTextBox.Focus();
outputTextBox.Select(outputTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
outputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
```

But after this, only the later is scrolled to the end. Is there a way to scroll these two textboxes to the end?

The binded text fields (`FileToConvert` and `OutputFilePath`) are being updated with buttons and stuff.

Comment: Pretty sure scrolling is not what you are looking for. The first `TextBox` is scrolling back to the beginning after losing focus. Have you tried setting a zero-length selection at the end  of the text? You'll have to set [`SelectionStart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart?view=net-5.0) and [`SelectionLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Hi! Yes, I have tried with the 
`inputTextBox.SelectionStart = inputTextBox.Text.Length; inputTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;` method as well, and it doesn't work. As far as I know, the `inputTextBox.Select(inputTextBox.Text.Length, 0);` Should be the same thing. Am I right?

Comment: I believe so, yes. I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions, but I hope you get an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `TextChanged` event like this:

```
void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex)
        .Right);
}

InputTextBlock.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
OutputTextBlock.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this comment! However, I get an error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from System.Windows.Rect to double`

Comment: Hi again! I figured it out, thank you so much for this, after a little tweaking, here's the working code piece: `inputTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(inputTextBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(inputTextBox.Text.Length).Right);` now, all I had to do was to apply that same to the other textbox as well and it works! Thank you!